# Loading data asynchronously to Dojo Tooltip's getContent()

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip

Here is an example of using getContent to display Dojo tooltip based on the element the mouse hovers over:

```
require(["dijit/Tooltip", "dojo/query!css2", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Tooltip){
    new Tooltip({
        connectId: "myTable",
        selector: "tr",
        getContent: function(matchedNode){
            return matchedNode.getAttribute("tooltipText");
            // What if we want to load this asynchronously???
        }
    });
});
```

However this doesn't work if you try to load data asynchronously via getContent(). Does anyonw knows how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set 'async: true' in the data-dojo-config property, dojo loader will load modules asynchronously. This means only the modules that you require will be loaded, therefore you won't have dojo/* or dijit/* .

If you were running into this issue on JsFiddle, all you need to do is to change the Framework & Extensions from 'onLoad' to 'No wrap - in < head>', so dojo loader is called in before require is. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/stafamus/L3y9v2nL/). Please note the fiddle option:

```
data-dojo-config="async:true"
```